# What would be the fastest way to transfer information from a 2d vector into a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

So I have a 2d vector `vector<vector<string> tokensArray;` and I want to put each element of it into a map: `map<string, vector<string>> tokens;`. What would be the fastest way of doing this? I would like it to be where the string of `map<*string*, vector<string>>` to be `tokensArray[any number][0]` and the vector of `map <string, *vector<string*>>` to be made up of `tokensArray[any number][1, 2, 3, etc]`.

so if the vector was:

```
vector<vector<string> tokensArray = { {"hello", "person", "word"} {"bye", "people", "sentence"} }
```

the map should be like:

```
map<string, vector<string>> tokens;
tokens["hello"] = {"person", "word"};
tokens["bye"] = {"people", "sentence"};
```

Comment: You need a loop for that, and writing it is obvious

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ya I tried using the loop and assigning them like `for(int i.....){
for(int j....){
token[ tokensArray[i][0] ] = {tokensArray[i][j]};
}`

when I did this I got an error: vector subscript is out of range

Comment: @Low_level_dir That means that either `i` or `j` is larger than the size of the vector you're indexing. Make sure your inner for-loop has as a stop condition: `j < tokensArray[i].size()`.

Comment: @bnaecker It did! And yet it gave me that error. I tried it many ways but it still gave me that

Comment: @Low_level_dir If you are doing `for (int j = 0; j < tokensArray[i].size(); j++)` in the inner for-loop, then it should be fine. So there is likely some other error in your code. Please edit your question by adding the exact code you tried.

Comment: @Low_level_dir: don't comment your own question but **edit your question** to improve it. Provide some [MCVE]; without one your question is unclear and off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        map<string, vector<string>> tokens;
    for (auto &v : input) {
        if (v.size() > 1) {
            tokens[v[0]] = vector<string>(v.begin() + 1, v.end()); // Create a new vector copy starting from second index.
        }
    }
```